# Get integer value/position for keys in the sub array of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, arrays

I have multi-dimensional array where I'm trying to output an integer value for the keys in the second array (sub array).

My array is pretty basic, like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'a' => 'd',
        'b' => 'e',
        'c' => 'f'
    ),
    array(
        'a' => 'x',
        'b' => 'y',
        'c' => 'z'
    ),
);
```

So when I create a foreach for that array...

```
foreach ( $array as $array_key => $sub_array ) {
    foreach ( $sub_array as $key => $value ) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

I output `$key` in the sub-loop and that just returns the array's key values, which are `a, b, c - a, b, c`

How can I actually get the integer value or position of those key values in the sub-array? So for each grouping in the array, `a` would be **1**, `b` would be **2**, `c` would be **3**. Then it would start over for the next grouping in the array.

I've tried using `$int++;` but that applies to both groups in the array, resulting in it going from 1-6, instead of 1-3, 1-3, etc.

Could something with `array_keys` work on this? Any help, as always, would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
foreach ( $array as $array_key => $sub_array ) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $sub_array as $key => $value ) {
        echo $i . ' - ' $key . '   ';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This will give you an expected result.

```
1 - a  2 - b   3 - c  1 - a  2 - b   3 - c
```

And if you use the this code below.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $array as $array_key => $sub_array ) {
    foreach ( $sub_array as $key => $value ) {
        echo $i . ' - ' $key . '   ';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This is the result.

```
1 - a  2 - b   3 - c  4 - a  5 - b   6 - c
```

Which is the output you encountered, not you expect. Note the location of the variable `$i`.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate the assistance sir! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Had no idea you could do that, amazing.